# Android Back button behaves unpredictably on Activity started from Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back

In my application I have 3 activities:

- `MainActivity`, which is the main screen which comes up when launching the app
- `SettingsActivity`, which is started from `MainActivity`
- `DownloadActivity`, which is started from `SettingsActivity`.

`DownloadActivity` presents a list of in-app content for users to download. The actual download is handled by Android's `DownloadManager`, which displays a notification for the downloads in progress. Tapping that notification will fire an intent, which will take the user to `DownloadActivity`.

Now if I do the following:

1. Start the app, go to `SettingsActivity`, from there to `DownloadActivity`.
2. Start a download, then hit Back twice to go back to `MainActivity`.
3. Pull down the notifications and tap the download nofification, which takes me back to `DownloadActivity`.
4. Hit Back.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 twice.

The first time I execute step 4, the Back button will take me straight from `DownloadActivity` to `MainActivity` – the last activity the app displayed before I hit the notification, which is what I want.

The second time, however, the Back button will reveal a second `DownloadActivity` underneath the current one, and I need to hit Back a second time to get back to `MainActivity`.

The third time, there is a stack of 4 `DownloadActivity` instances, requiring four presses of the `Back` button to return to `MainActivity`.

The code that handles the tap is the following:

```
Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), downloadActivity.class);
downloadIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
activity.getApplicationContext().startActivity(downloadIntent);
```

(`activity` is a reference to the activity which started the download.)

What is causing this odd behavior, and how can I make the Back button always return to the last activity the app displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an easy one. This change did the trick:

```
- downloadIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
+ downloadIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```